# Window Performance not working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 var navigationStartTime                = window.performance.timing.navigationStart;

        function domTimingRecordEvents(){
            var domEventObject = {};
            var domArray = [];

            domEventObject.domLoadingStartTime            = (window.performance.timing.domLoading - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            domEventObject.domInteractiveTime             = (window.performance.timing.domInteractive - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            domEventObject.domContentLoadedEventStartTime = (window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventStart - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            domEventObject.domContentLoadedEventEndTime   = (window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            domEventObject.domCompleteTime                = (window.performance.timing.domComplete - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            domEventObject.loadEventStartTime             = (window.performance.timing.loadEventStart - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            //var loadEventEndTime               = (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - navigationStartTime)/1000;
            
            domArray.push(domEventObject);
            console.table(domArray);          
        }   

domTimingRecordEvents();
```

1. My code above works in chrome and firefox smoothly but gives error when run in opera browser.
2. I checked console in opera window returns window but window.performance  returns undefined
3. In above code I get time in seconds after calculation of various page events in javascript.
4. Should i use :-

.

```
 var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
```

And skip the code above or there is any alternate way ?

Comment: It does not work on Firefox... or Chrome for that matter!

Comment: @Angelos:- I do get the timings in chrome and firefox console. just type in console everything apart from the addEvent line and call the function domTimingRecordEvents();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows performance it's something new in JavaScript, and all browser do not support all functionalities yet.

Please check this documentation from Mozilla to know which functionalities are implemented for each browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: Actually I had an old version of Opera installed. Around 12.0 version or something so it was not working but when I installed the latest version window.performance worked. So your answer is correct. Thanks !!!